# Odoo Hide Many2one Field when Empty

Tags: odoo

I have a `Many2one` field that I want to hide when there is no value. I try from [this solution](https://www.odoo.com/id_ID/forum/bantuan-1/make-a-many2one-field-invisible-when-is-empty-99464), but it didn't work and give me an error when trying to upgrade.

```
<field name="parent_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the field to be hidden when it is empty, the code is as follows:

`<field name="parent_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id', '=', False)]}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and I solved this with define a dummy field in my model and use this in view like this:
'''

```
    hide = fields.Boolean(string="Hide", compute="_set_hide", store=False)
    @api.depends('parent_id')
    def _set_hide(self):
        if self.parent_id.id:
            self.hide = False
        else:
            self.hide = True
```

'''
and in xml you should write like this:

```
 <field name="hide" invisible="1"/>
 <field name="parent_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('hide', '='True)]}"/>
```